# Remove div element by Class

Tags: javascript

To remove element `ID` I use `document.getElementById("your-id").remove();`

For `Class` I use code below but It's not working:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("hide1").remove();
```

```html
<div class=hide1>
  <center>Hide Me</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, `<center>` doesn't exist anymore. Don't use it. Use CSS.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know that until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only one, you can use `querySelector`:

```js
document.querySelector(".hide1").remove();
```

```html
<div class=hide1>
  <center>Hide Me</center>
</div>
```

If you're using getElementsByClassName, you'll be dealing with a NodeList you'll have to iterate over:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("hide1")].forEach(el=>el.remove());
```

```html
<div class=hide1>
  <center>Hide Me</center>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked like GEM, Thanks a lot my friend.